# Set value in the multiple select input with javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I have problem to set multiple values in the multiple select input. For example I need to set value 2,3 (Ketchup, Relish) in the multi-select input when I've clicked the `Show Selected Option` button, then the value will show in the input field.

Below is I want the expected result:

[image: example 1]

Below is my coding that I've tried, I've used this method  `$('.selectpicker').val(value);` but it cannot work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<select class="selectpicker" value="" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc()">Show Selected Option</button>
<script>
$('select').selectpicker();

function sendFunc(){
    var value = "2,3";
    $('.selectpicker').val(value);
}
</script>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Please read the documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) for selecting items with programmatically with code. They have made it extremely clear on how to do this.

...From the docs linked above:

> You can set the selected value by calling the val method on the element.
> `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['Mustard','Relish']);`

Key think to notice here is that the values are an array, not a string.

Calling `.val()` directly like in your code works differently to the above - you should read on further on the docs page to understand the difference compared to `.selectpicker('val')`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<select class="selectpicker" value="" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc()">Show Selected Option</button>
<script>
$('select').selectpicker();

function sendFunc(){
    var value = [2,3];
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val',value);
}
</script>
```